# What is the correct link to open bitcoin wallets with address and amount?

Tags: android, ios, blockchain, bitcoin, wallet

We are developing an Android/iOS application that accepts coin payments. Our application creates a link with amount and address like bitcoin:[btcaddress]?amount=[floatAmount]

This link covered by a button which name is "Pay With Bitcoin App" and contains this link.

Links works with "Bitcoin.com Wallet", opens the payment page with address and amount. **But** Coinomi Wallet **can't open** the payment page. Its shows "There was a problem scanning: Unsupported address: *bitcoin:[address]?amount:[amount]* "

Bitcoin.com Wallet https://wallet.bitcoin.com/

Coinomi Wallet https://www.coinomi.com/en/downloads/

Coinomi Wallet Github code shows: https://github.com/Coinomi/coinomi-android/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/coinomi/core/uri/CoinURI.java (on line: 63 and 64)

In summary;
If an user clicks the button (bitcoin:[btcaddress]?amount=[floatAmount]) in my app, coinomi does not open bitcoin wallet page in their app. But bitcoin.com wallet is working with this link.

**EDIT:** I asked to Coinomi Developer team. They already fixed in development version of Coinomi Wallet. So, it will be fixed on next version.

Comment: You didn't post an answer, but your "edit" looks like an answer. What do you still need help with?

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, i could not find solved button or selected answer button.

Comment: There is a box below where you can write your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I asked to Coinomi Developer team. They already fixed in development version of Coinomi Wallet. So, it will be fixed on next version.